# How can I crop a video to a part of the view?

Tags: ubuntu, video-editing

I have a video that shows the following

[image]

and I would like to crop it to this:

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried yet and where did you get stuck? I'm sure there are dozens of tools that allow cropping video, so it might help to ask a more specific question, else we get a list of software that crops video – which is considered *not constructive*

Comment: I tried to find an application that supports this. I only found `ffmpeg`, but `ffmpeg -croptop 90 -i original.ogv "output.ogv"` gave me `Vertical crop dimensions are outside the range of the original image`. I did not find any graphical program for this task.

Comment: I would be happy if you could name me *one* program, that does allow me to crop by place, not by time.

Comment: Adobe Premiere, [`ffmpeg` crop filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#crop), [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/), QuickTime Pro, iMovie, [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/), [VidCrop](http://www.geovid.com/vidcrop/) …

Comment: The `ffmpeg` syntax with `croptop` is quite old and won't be supported  in any somewhat recent versions. You'll need to use the `-filter:v` command, see FFmpeg documentation.

Comment: People who come to this question might look for software to cut a video (so only the first 10 seconds or something similar). See [What to use to quickly cut Audio/Video](http://askubuntu.com/q/56022/10425) for that.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

#### Cropping with FFmpeg

With [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/), cropping works as follows, using the [`crop`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#crop) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=out_w:out_h:x:y" out.mp4
```

Where the options are as follows:

- `out_w` is the width of the output rectangle
- `out_h` is the height of the output rectangle
- `x` and `y` specify the top left corner of the output rectangle

So, for example, to crop a 640×480 window, starting from position (100, 100), you'd do:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=640:480:100:100" out.mp4
```

Be aware that FFmpeg will re-encode the video using x264, when the MP4 container is selected. With no additional options, this defaults to a constant rate factor ([CRF](http://slhck.info/video/2017/02/24/crf-guide.html)) set to 23. To increase the quality—which could be necessary for screen recordings with sharp edges and text—use a lower value, maybe go down to 18:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=640:480:100:100" -crf 18 out.mp4
```

---

#### Cropping with Handbrake

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) is a free and open source cross-platform tool with a GUI. Load the input file, then use the *Picture Settings* to specify the crop:

[image]

You can use the *Preview Window* to visually adjust the crop.

Here, you can also adjust the output quality with the *Constant Quality* slider:

[image]

Comment: In handbrake 1.2.2 the crop setting is in Dimensions tab of the main window.

Answer (score 3):

Did you use *Ubuntu*'s default *recordMyDesktop* tool?  If so, click "Select Window" and then draw a rectangle on the thumbnail it shows of your current desktop.  This area will be recorded.  This is not "cropping a video" but "cropping a scene" but I think it should solve your problem at hand...

Comment: As I have started the program inside of VirtualBox and I want to record it from the outside, I can't select the window. So this answer doesn't help (btw.: yes, I used recordmydesktop, but without a GUI which makes choosing a window quite difficult)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a program called ['Footage' by Khaleel Al-Adhami.](https://flathub.org/apps/io.gitlab.adhami3310.Footage)  If that link doesn't work, [Try this link as well](https://gitlab.com/adhami3310/Footage)  It can crop, trim, flip and rotate.