# Crop video to custom resolution

Tags: video, crop, transcode

I'm just looking for a simple application (preferably free but not necessarily) that allows me to crop a video to a custom resolution; obviously smaller than the original resolution.  The application can be windows or Mac.

I have an 1920 x 1080 video that needs scaling down to 210px in height and then cropping width to 150px down the middle.

I've found a few but such as Avidemux and virtual dub but they seem to be overly complex and export to odd formats that don't seem to work.

Comment: Duplicate: [How can I crop a video to a part of the view?](http://superuser.com/questions/510985/how-can-i-crop-a-video-to-a-part-of-the-view/511151#511151)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you give a second chance to [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/), its not so complex and one you get the flow is pretty easy to use. VirtualDub by default doesn't pack all the codecs, so if you for example want to encode in H264, you will need to get [h264vfw](http://sourceforge.net/projects/x264vfw/). Once you have the codec, you should be able to check it from VirtualDub's options.

The steps to resize/crop a video should be the following:

1. Open the video in VirtualDub.
2. Goto Video > Filters. Click on Add and select the filter you want to apply (resize in this case).
3. Configure resize options.
4. Once any filter is configured, you can click on cropping, then select the cropping you want. Click ok when finished.
5. Goto Video > Compression and select the codec you want to use. Once selected, you should be able to click on the configure button if you want to further configure the encoding options.
6. Click File > Save as avi to encode the video in a new file.

If the video has audio, you can configure it in the Audio Options. You will need to have an audio codec (LAME or other) to be able to reencode the audio. Also you can rely on the option to copy the audio as it is or extract the audio, convert it with an external program (Audacity for example) and then join it to the video.

Comment: The save as AVI thing was confusing but after a bit more fiddling around this was exactly what I needed to do!