# How to convert a Voluson 4D ultrasound scan (.V00 file) to a video?

Tags: video, file-conversion

I have here a "4D volume cine" ultrascound scan (time series of 3D scans) created with a machine from [GE Healthcare Voluson](http://www3.gehealthcare.com/en/products/categories/ultrasound/voluson). The file is in their older, proprietary `.V00` format.

I want to create a video file from this that can be played in a normal media player. How to do that, ideally with freely available tools?

Comment: That's a super specific question. Under normal circumstances, I'd hope for an example file, but this might not be an option here?

Comment: Yes sorry, I'm not free to publish the files I'm working on. Then there's the GE Healthcare [4D View Demo Cases gallery](http://www.volusonclub.net/us/gevolumes), but unfortunately only accessible with a login that requires you to own one of their ultrasound units :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.V00` files are the "Kretzfile" / "Kretz 3D Ultrasound Images" format [[source](http://fixunix.com/dicom/50181-ge-3d-ultrasound-data-file-format.html#post182895)]. The connection between GE Healthcare and Kretz is because "In 2001, GE Medical Systems acquired a major shareholding in Kretztechnik AG from Medison, and Kretztechnik AG became a wholly owned subsidiary of GE Medical Systems" [[source](http://www.tomovision.com/products/format_image.html)].

**You can use [4D View](http://www.volusonclub.net/us/4dview).** This is the "official" PC software provided by GE Healthcare for their Voluson ultrasound imaging machines. Example process on how to export to a video with it:

1. Open the file in 4D View and choose "File → Export 4D Img. Cine Sequence…".
2. Tick the option "Compression" (except if you want postprocessing in step 4, don't use compression to prevent [a bug](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3270)). Leave "Reduction Ratio" at "1.00 : 1", as else it would downscale the video resolution.
3. Click "Save" to export the 4D volume to `.avi` format. What you get should look like a [replay in 4D View](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhfPHgupikg), just without all the lettering.
4. To remove the huge black borders from the video, to connect multiple exported videos and to convert it all into a small MP4 format, you can run the following [`ffmpeg`](https://ffmpeg.org/) command in a Linux shell, while in a directory that contains your exported, uncompressed `.avi` files and nothing else:

   ```
   ffmpeg \
     -i concat:"$(ls -l *.avi | awk 'BEGIN {ORS="|"} { print $9 }')" \
     -filter:v "crop=400:380:332:175" \
     -r 25 \
     -crf 18 \
     output.mp4
   ```

   This is based on [several](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15186625) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19314483) [answers](https://superuser.com/a/511151). If you have [`avconv`](https://libav.org/avconv.html) instead, it works with the same parameters. It assumes 400×380 px content starting at x=332, y=175 (that is, about centered on a 1068×740 px video) – adapt the `crop=` parameter values to your case if needed by measuring on a stillframe. `-crf 18` selects a higher quality than the default `-crf 23`, at the expense of bigger file size. I doubt if the quality improvement is visible though …
5. For archiving purposes, you might want to store the individual AVI videos (huge if uncompressed!) in a nice lossless or near-lossless format, without concatenating them, but again removing the useless black border:

   ```
   for file in *.avi; do
     ffmpeg \
       -i $file \
       -c:v libx264 \
       -preset veryslow \
       -crf 1 \
       -r 25 \
       -filter:v "crop=400:380:332:175" \
       ${file/.avi/.mp4};
   done
   ```

   This uses H.264 with quantizer value 1 (`-crf 1`), which is very near lossless [[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1011218)] and 25 times smaller than the original uncompressed AVIs. You can also use `-crf 0` or better `-qp 0` instead, which will result in truly lossless H.264. It is about 20% larger, and not all players can read it [[details](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#LosslessH.264)]. But VLC and YouTube can, for example.

Some hints on obtaining and installing 4D View:

- 4D View is available as licenced software, a 60-day unrestricted demo version, and a non-expiring de-featured version [[see](http://www.volusonclub.net/us/4dview)]. All seem capable of exporting to `.avi` files, but I did only try with the 60-day demo.
- The newer versions of 4D View can only be downloaded by registered owners of Voluson machines (you need to sign up and give your machine's serial number; but maybe they will make an exception if you ask kindly). Earlier versions were publicly downloadable however, and are [still available](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Tf-XZtpLz-bVc1VExENE9Ranc/view) on the web.
- 4D View is made for Windows 7, but can also be installed in Windows XP etc..
- 4D View can not be used in a virtual machine, at least not in VirtualBox with Windows XP guest (and 3D acceleration enabled). When trying to start it, 4D View will complain "No sufficient graphic card found or driver not installed" and exit.

Some more details and contacts around converting V00 files can be found in [this comp.protocols.dicom thread](http://compgroups.net/comp.protocols.dicom/kretz-v00-files-from-ge-volusion-730-son/2268701). For background info, there is also the [Voluson S6 / S8 Service Manual](http://medsensor.ru/data/PARKONIRMS/attachments/dd/files/2.1.2.4/Voluson_S6S8_SM.pdf). For tests, here is a hard-to-find [3D scan in Kretzfile format](http://sydney.edu.au/medicine/nepean/research/obstetrics/pelvic-floor-assessment/Pelvic_Floor_Assessment/4D_View_intro.html) for download; just 3D though, so not allowing the 4D-to-`.avi` conversion with 4D View.

**Not possible: [4DTheFetusView](http://www.sonoworld.com/fetus/page.aspx?id=1503).** This tool is the same as a 2005 version of 4D View and still available for free download. Except, it can only be used to open demo volumes shared via [sonoworld.com](http://sonoworld.com/). These 4D demo volumes had been attached to several of [their cases](http://sonoworld.com/TheFetus/listing.aspx?id=2) (incl. [this](http://sonoworld.com/fetus/page.aspx?id=1517), [this](http://sonoworld.com/TheFetus/Case.aspx?CaseId=1622&answer=1), [this](http://sonoworld.com/TheFetus/Case.aspx?CaseId=1508&answer=1)) but are no longer available for download.

**Not possible: [DICOMatic](http://www.tomovision.com/products/dicomatic.html).** This is a freely downloadable conversion tool that can convert a multitude of proprietary medical imaging formats to the new standard format [DICOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICOM). Just that an unregistered version watermarks exported images [[source](http://www.tomovision.com/download/download_dicomatic.html)]. From DICOM, one could proceed with the freely available tools [MicroDICOM](http://www.microdicom.com/downloads.html) or [DICOM Cine Viewer](http://www.fpimage.com/cineplayer.html) to export a video file. However, for the GE KretzFile format, DICOMatic notes that "DICOM do[es] not support 3D volumes for ultrasound images" [[source](http://www.tomovision.com/products/format_image.html)]. When trying to open a .V00 file in DICOMatic, I got the note that it does not support polar coordinates. Probably that's equivalent to saying that 3D volumes are not supported (?). So, it did not work (for me), but the manufacturer says that it should work [[source](http://fixunix.com/dicom/50181-ge-3d-ultrasound-data-file-format.html#post182895)].

**Not possible: [TomoVision](http://www.tomovision.com/products/tomovision.html) and a screengrabber.** TomoVision is a viewer for medical image formats, so if it could render .V00 sequences, one could convert it to a video with a screengrabber. However, since it uses the same library as DICOMatic [[source](http://www.tomovision.com/products/tomovision.html)], it will also be unable to read the 4D volume. Though again, the manufacturer claims it should be possible [[source](http://fixunix.com/dicom/50181-ge-3d-ultrasound-data-file-format.html#post182895)].

Comment: I got it running in VirtualBox with, Windows 7 with 3D acceleration enabled

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a GE/Kretz 3D ultrasound image reader in 3D Slicer. After you have loaded the image you can use all the awesome tools in 3D Slicer to visualize and process it (for example, to create a 3D-printable model). You can see a demo here:

https://youtu.be/UHq0uyDvhaA

It's not perfect yet (spherical to Cartesian conversion is not fully accurate), but it's completely free and open-source - fixes and improvements are welcome. For further details and questions please post to the 3D Slicer forum:

https://discourse.slicer.org/t/loading-of-ge-kretz-ultrasound-volumes-vol-file/808/14?u=lassoan

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've exported a Voluson file without compression enabled (Wavelet = 'Off') and with the Volume/Raw File selected... try using this script to see if your data is in third-party DICOM format. This doesn't reconstruct the data into a useable format but does show if you can access the element data.

```
import struct
import sys

class GETagAnalyser(object):

def __init__(self,fname):
    self.m_fname = None
    if fname is not None:
        self.m_fname = fname
    self.m_tagdict = [] 

def readAllTags(self):
    with open(self.m_fname,'rb') as f:
        hdr = f.read(16)
        print hdr
        #find end
        f.seek(0,2)    
        fend = f.tell()
        print fend
        #back to start
        f.seek(16,0) 
        while f.tell() <= fend-4:
            t1,t2,s,tag_data,f = self.readNextTag(f)    
            #self.m_tagdict                
            print hex(t1), hex(t2),s    
            #print t1, t2, s


def readNextTag(self,f):
    firsttag = f.read(2)
    firsttag = struct.unpack('@H',firsttag)

    secondtag = f.read(2)
    secondtag = struct.unpack('@H',secondtag)

    size = f.read(4)
    size = struct.unpack('@I',size)    
    data = f.read(size[0])

    tag1,tag2,size,data = firsttag[0],secondtag[0],size[0],data
    return tag1,tag2,size,data,f

def main():

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print "Usage: GETagAnalyser <inputfile>"
    return
g = GETagAnalyser(sys.argv[1])
#print sys.argv[1]
g.readAllTags()
```