# How to convert a GE Voluson file to cartesian format?

Tags: 3d, file-conversion

I am looking to convert a 3D model from a GE Healthcare Voluson E8 ultrasonic imaging machine into a file in cartesian format (layered). However, converting to DICOM format results in spherical / polar coordinates.

The source format is a `.4dv` Voluson file. The only place I can open them is with GE's own [4D View](http://www.volusonclub.net/us/4dview) software, which needs me to actually own a machine to obtain it! It appears from a Google search that I could convert with 4D View into cartesian format.

Does anyone know an alternative way, or if the 4D View software is available to obtain or buy separately?

Answer (score 0):

GE Healthcare Voluson [4D View](http://www.volusonclub.net/us/4dview) is available as licensed software, as a 60-day unrestricted demo version, and as a non-expiring de-featured version [[see](http://www.volusonclub.net/us/4dview)]. The newer versions of 4D View, in all of these variants, can only be downloaded by registered owners of Voluson ultrasonic imaging machines (you need to sign up and give your machine's serial number). So your options include:

- Ask kindly if they would make an exception, at least for the demo version.
- Get an earlier version. These earlier versions were publicly downloadable, and are [still available](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Tf-XZtpLz-bVc1VExENE9Ranc/view) on the web.

Hopefully the earlier version is able to open your `.4dv` files. I do not know however if it can export to cartesian versions (as you say), but you can try it now. Some more details about 4D View are in this [related question](https://superuser.com/q/884196/191090).